# How can I solve MemoryError if I have big list in my Arcpy code?

Tags: arcpy, list, memoryerror

I have a script and I have a huge list.
Because of this list, I got memory error in line 93 when the value of scale variable is 10000 in line 45.

This list is empty_list in line 28. I tried to convert it to numpy array but I got a iterator error

Here is the script:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os

source = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
result = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
if result == '#' or not result:
    result = "D:\\eotr"
scale = arcpy.GetParameter(2)

tMapsheetScales = [500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 10000, 25000, 50000, 100000, 200000]
tDXY = [[375,250], [750,500], [1500,1000], [3000,2000], [6000,4000], [12000,8000], [24000,16000], [48000,32000], [96000,64000]]

ind_tMapsheet = tMapsheetScales.index(scale)
value_tDXY = tDXY[ind_tMapsheet]
aDx, aDy = value_tDXY

Output_Labels = ""
fish100K = "in_memory\\fish100K"
fish100K_Layer = "fish100K_Layer"
fish100K_Layer__2_ = fish100K_Layer

arcpy.CreateFishnet_management(fish100K, "384000 32000", "384000 64000", aDx, aDy, "", "", "960000 384000", "NO_LABELS", "DEFAULT", "POLYGON")

numbers_back = ['9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
one_to_four = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
empty_list = []
other_empty_list = []

for k in numbers_back:
    for l in numbers:
        if scale == 100000:
            other_empty_list.append(k + l)
        elif scale == 50000:
            for m in one_to_four:
                other_empty_list.append(k + l + '-' + m)
        elif scale == 25000:
            list_25000 = []
            for m in one_to_four:
                list_25000.append(k + l + '-' + m)
            for n in list_25000:
                for o in one_to_four:
                    other_empty_list.append(n + o)
        elif scale == 10000:
            list_25000 = []
            list_10000 = []
            for m in one_to_four:
                list_25000.append(k + l + '-' + m)
            for n in list_25000:
                for o in one_to_four:
                    list_10000.append(n + o)
            del list_25000
            for p in list_10000:
                for o in one_to_four:
                    other_empty_list.append(p + o)
            del list_10000

del empty_list[:]
empty_list.extend(other_empty_list)

del other_empty_list [:]


for i in fish100K:
    arcpy.AddField_management(fish100K, "tile_name", "TEXT", 20)


arcpy.AddField_management(fish100K, "LEFT", "DOUBLE", 9)
arcpy.AddField_management(fish100K, "TOP", "DOUBLE", 9)
arcpy.AddField_management(fish100K, "RIGHT", "DOUBLE", 9)
arcpy.AddField_management(fish100K, "BOTTOM", "DOUBLE", 9)

fields = ["LEFT", "TOP", "RIGHT", "BOTTOM"]
fieldToUpdate = ''
shapeName = arcpy.Describe(fish100K).shapeFieldName
cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fish100K)
for row in cur:
    poly = row.getValue(shapeName)
    ext = poly.extent
    x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = ext.XMin, ext.XMax, ext.YMin, ext.YMax
    row.setValue("LEFT", x_min)
    row.setValue("TOP", y_max)
    row.setValue("RIGHT", x_max)
    row.setValue("BOTTOM", y_min)
    val = row.getValue("tile_name")
    arcpy.AddMessage(val)
    cur.updateRow(row)
del cur, row

fieldToUpdate = 'tile_name'
featurecount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fish100K).getOutput(0))
empty_list = iter(empty_list*featurecount)
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fish100K, fieldToUpdate) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = next(empty_list2)
        cursor.updateRow(row)

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fish100K, fish100K_Layer, "", "", "")
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fish100K_Layer, "INTERSECT", source, "", "NEW_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fish100K_Layer__2_, result, "", "0", "0", "0")
```

Comment: How "huge" is your list? How much RAM on the system? Have you installed 64-bit ArcPy (either ArcMap 64-bit geoprocessing or Pro)? The days for "old-style" cursors ended a decade ago -- code that uses in_memory should only use DA cursors.

Comment: The len(empty_list) == 6400 and it would be more if I move on next scale value.
My system has 12 GB RAM but I got the same error on an other pc that has 16 GB RAM
I use ArcMap 10.4.1

Comment: You only get ~1GiB in a 32-bit process, no matter how much physical RAM the system has.

Comment: So.. what sould I do now?

Comment: How about 1) use a DA cursor, and 2) Install 10.4.1  Background geoprocessing and all the patches issued for 10.4.1 Desktop (or start using Pro)

Answer (score 2):

This is a really inefficient way to insert a repeating sequence of values, because you're building up the list with redundant data until it's as large as the number of features.  You don't need to hold all of that in memory.

```
fieldToUpdate = 'tile_name'
featurecount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fish100K).getOutput(0))
empty_list = iter(empty_list*featurecount)
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fish100K, fieldToUpdate) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = next(empty_list2)
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Instead you can use the modulo operator to wrap the row's index to fit the list's

```
fieldToUpdate = 'tile_name'
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fish100K, fieldToUpdate) as cursor:
    for i, row in enumerate(cursor):
        row[0] = empty_list[i % len(empty_list)]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

There are more problems with the code as pointed out in the comments above, but that addresses the memory error on line 93 specifically.

Edit: looking at this again, you're not even using the result of line 93 and you reference an undefined variable inside of the loop